# Changing a menu link used in the sitemap module but not in main nav

Tags: 8, theming

We are using the [Sitemap](https://www.drupal.org/project/sitemap) module for creating a sitemap generated from three menus (Footer, Main nav and a 3rd arbitrary one).

In the main nav we have a placeholder LI element which we use to insert a view.

In the sitemap template we need to replace this placeholder with some content without affecting the main nav.

In the sitemap overridden template where `{{ item.content }}` normally appears I tried replacing with the following:

```
{{ item.content|replace('>LRGPH_BRANCHES_BY_SERVICE<', ('>' ~ allBranches ~ '<')) }}
```

Note: `allBranches` is a concatenation of the output of 4 views (Essentially pure HTML)

but Twig/Drupal seems to have issue with this as I get an error, as per below:

> Warning: strtr() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in twig_replace_filter() (line 521 of /var/www/vendor/twig/twig/src/Extension/CoreExtension.php).
>       twig_replace_filter(Array, '>LRGPH_BRANCHES_BY_SERVICE<', '>

I next tried using the contributed modules hook, namely `function TEMPLATE_preprocess_sitemap(&$variables)` but although I can see the HTML output of the sitemap I cannot change it using this as far as I can tell.

Is there any way to achieve this change at all without altering the Main navigation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`{{ something.content }}` is a render array, you can't do a string replace on an array. But you can store the computed string output of the render array, and do a string replace on the rendered output:

```
{# compute the output of the render array and store it #}
{% set rendered_html_string = item.content|render %}

{# do the replacement #}
{% set modified_string = rendered_html_string|replace('seachtext', 'replacetext') %}

{# print the modified string #}
{{ modified_html_string }}
```